# Pass values from Server to Client | Node to Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mean

I'm very new to MEAN. I'm trying to send a dataset from Node to my Angular Controller. However, the angular controller isn't receiving the correct information and is resulting in null.

My view is called `booklist.jade`

Here is my server side (Node JS)

```
router.get('/thelist', function(req, res){

    res.render('booklist');
  });

router.get('/thelist/data', function(req, res){

   .
   .
   .

    // Find all books
    collection.find({}).toArray(function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err);
      } else if (result.length) {
        res.json({booklist : result});
      } else {
        res.send('No documents found');
      }
      //Close connection
      db.close();
    });
  }
  });
});
```

Here is my client side (Angular JS)

```
function booksController($scope)
{
    $http.get("http://localhost:3000/thelist/data").success(function( data ) {
    $scope.book=10; //THIS WORKS
    $scope.table= data;
});
}
```

Basically, I want $scope.table to have all data from my server. Any ideas on why this is failing?

UPDATE: On trying some console log checks, I found out that the request `router.get('/thelist/data', function(req, res)` isn't being called by the Angular Controller.

Comment: Are you sure your node code is written properly i.e. do you have unit tests? You might want to refactor out the code that does the work, stick it into a separate script or module or whatever, and test that it works properly - i.e. isolate the issue, right now it could be the angular call failing, or it could be your script not working properly.

Comment: Did u console the data response coming from http request ?

Comment: The only problem I'm facing is that `router.get('/thelist/data', function(req, res)` is never called by the Angular Controller.

Comment: @Wcan the http request function is a success but the data is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My client side controller was wrong. Here is the correct one.

```
app.controller('booksController',['$scope','$http',
    function($scope,$http) {
        $http.get("http://localhost:3000/thelist/data").success(function( data ) {
            $scope.book=data;

        });
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`res.json({booklist : result});`

as per your code you are sending result in `booklist` attribute

Hence while reading you should say  `$scope.table= data.booklist;`

Comment: that still gives null.

Comment: can you add console log?

Comment: Hi Rohit: I think the problem is that this request `router.get('/thelist/data', function(req, res)` isn't being called by the Angular Controller.

Comment: Please show the code how is it u r displaying the data, also @Rohit Shedage pointed the right thing, why don't u just do res.json({result}) and then get data by data.result just to check if its working

Comment: Also when u say result.lenght, result.length what ? Is it telling u no document found ? U need to compare result.length with simething atleast 1 or just directly console the result part inside collection.find and u'll know what is the problem